# mirror: Access failed: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/dist/*: No such file or directory

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

i am new in using bitbucket pipelines. I have an issue related with deploying my dist file to ftp server. this is an error "mirror: Access failed: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/dist/*: No such file or directory" that occurs when i am trying to deploy project.
this is my bitbucket.yml file

```html
#  Template NodeJS build

#  This template allows you to validate your NodeJS code.
#  The workflow allows running tests and code linting on the default branch.

image: node:16

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Install dependencies
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install
          artifacts:
            - node_modules/** # Save modules for next steps
      - step:
          name: Build project
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm run build
          artifacts:
            - dist/** # Save build for next steps
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          trigger: manual
          deployment: Production
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/ftp-deploy:0.3.7
              variables:
                USER: $FTP_USERNAME
                PASSWORD: $FTP_PASSWORD
                SERVER: $FTP_HOST
                REMOTE_PATH: '/var/www/*******/booking.crt-minds.ru/'
                LOCAL_PATH: 'dist/*'
                EXTRA_ARGS: "--exclude=.bitbucket/ --exclude=.git/ --exclude=bitbucket-pipelines.yml --exclude=.gitignore" # Ignore these
```

I have tried to delete local_path in yml and see what happened. but first of all i do not understand if my pipeline has access to ftp server. How can i check it? so then i need to understand how to replace dist folder files in ftp server? May be my bitbucket.yml file incorrect configured?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read the guidelines on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The better your question, the faster you will a good answer. Note that screenshots from error messages and source code are UNwelcome, please just use code blocks instead.

Answer (score 1):

Telling from the pipe's [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines/integrations?p=atlassian/ftp-deploy)

> `LOCAL_PATH`: Optional path to local directory to upload. Default `${BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR}`.

I bet it is interpreting the value you passed not as glob pattern but literally a folder named `dist/*`

Try to drop that `/*`:

```
      - step:
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/ftp-deploy:0.3.7
              variables:
                USER: $FTP_USERNAME
                PASSWORD: $FTP_PASSWORD
                SERVER: $FTP_HOST
                REMOTE_PATH: /var/www/site
                LOCAL_PATH: dist
```